# gap detection - identify what date was skipped / missed

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I have a database table where are records with an **ID** and **date** - date ranges.

There was imported dates for some ID-s initially to the **date to** column. I was interested only in the **months**, date like 2018-06-01 00:00:00 represents the whole iune month of 2018. (I am not interested in days and time, 01 day was set because I cant use 00).

The 2019-**01**-01 (date from) and 2019-**01**-01 (date to) represents **a month** (ianuary).

The 2018-**09**-01 (date from) and 2018-**11**-01 (date to) represents **an interval of months** (september 01 - november 31)

[image]

So what I want is to get the ID-s where are gaps, missed month or months intervals. How can I resolve this with sql? Which way do I start?

Comment: You will need a calendar table to start with. Do a left join from the calendar table to the main table, to figure out rows where there is no matching entry for the calendar month.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, I will make an online example

Comment: Are you using mysql 8.0 or bellow? The query can be quite different.

Comment: mysql 5.7 version I use, I will try your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x you can use correlated query (very slow) to identify the gaps. Rough outline of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, start_date, start_date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS prev_end_date_exp, (
        SELECT end_date
        FROM yourdata AS x
        WHERE id = t.id AND end_date < t.start_date
        ORDER BY end_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS prev_end_date_act
    FROM yourdata AS t
) AS sq
WHERE prev_end_date_exp <> prev_end_date_act
```

This will give you a list of rows that contain a gap between itself and previous row and the range (not the list) of dates.

Comment: Using your query I get another results than using the query of PeterHe, but now this will show all records with gaps? How can I determine? (all records returned are with gaps)

Comment: your query cant identify gaps like this: https://i.ibb.co/0D6hvrn/gap1.png but can identify https://i.ibb.co/W5Y8yVD/gap2.png

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that this correlated query shows the gaps between intervals, and PeterHe query shows the dates what are on each other (intervals that cover each others)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using 8.0, you can create a working table to hold the data:

```
 CREATE TABLE _gap_cal (
      ID int not null,
      date_to date not null,
      rid int not null auto_increment,
      date_from date null,
      PRIMARY KEY (ID,rid)
 ) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

Then populate the data like:

```
INSERT _gap_cal(ID,date_from,date_to,rid)
SELECT ID,COALESCE(date_from,'1900-01-01'),date_to,NULL
FROM your_data_table
ORDER BY ID,date_to;
```

For the test purpose, I just insert some data directly:

```
INSERT _gap_cal(ID,date_from,date_to,rid)
VALUES (6545,'1900-01-01','2018-06-01',NULL),
  (6545,'2018-09-01','2018-11-01',NULL),
  (6545,'2019-01-01','2019-01-01',NULL),
  (2421,'2019-04-01','2019-06-01',NULL),
  (2421,'2019-07-01','2019-07-01',NULL),
  (2421,'2019-09-01','2019-11-01',NULL);

SELECT * FROM _gap_cal;
```

The following query will give you the IDs and date ranges with gaps:

```
SELECT c.ID,c.date_from,c.date_to, p.date_from as previous_date_from
FROM _gap_cal p
INNER JOIN _gap_cal c
ON p.ID=c.ID
AND p.rid=c.rid-1
AND TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH,1, p.date_to)<>c.date_from
ORDER BY c.ID,c.date_from;
```

Comment: Can you explain your sql query please? with your query I get some records with gaps, if I use @Salman A query I get another records with gaps, but why?

Comment: this query can identify gaps like this https://i.ibb.co/0D6hvrn/gap1.png but cant identify gaps like this https://i.ibb.co/W5Y8yVD/gap2.png

Comment: So what I noticed, this query shows intervals, dates which are doubled.